# How do I set color to anchor link with only body style

Tags: css

Is there any way to set color to anchor link with only body style ? I would like to change anchor link color with only body style like below

For example:

```
body {
    color: red; 
}
```

and then anchor link will be *red*. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Tushar: If OP was happy with adding a descendant selector they might as well do `body a` (or for that matter even just a `*` without `body`). I don't understand why OP wants to do this with `body` (whatever the reason is, it doesn't sound like a good design to me) but the `body *` doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @Harry Yes, you're right about design. I'm wrong with `body *`, it should be `body a` as you've said, it's wrong thats why I've added it as comment. :)

Comment: Is there a reason to apply the style to anchors using `body`?

Comment: @Tushar I just do not want to write a lot of selectors for it

Comment: @SotaYamashita You can use `element` selector as `a { color: red; }`. This will apply styles to all the anchors on the page

Comment: If the other elements have styles for `a` set, then it will be hard time overwriting them with `body a { }` as they will have higher specificity. You may use `a { color: red !important; }` but using `!important` is discouraged.

Comment: @SotaYamashita: Please don't take it personally but that's a bit like saying *I can make my shirt a bit more lengthy to cover my bottom and so I don't need trousers*. There is absolutely nothing wrong in writing a separate selector to style the anchors and it isn't going to cause much difference in terms of performance, size or load times.

Comment: @Harry The asker just want to set the styles generally, he don't want to repeat himself to apply styles

Comment: @Tushar: There is a difference between setting styles generally and setting them at `body` atleast in my books. Writing `a{color: red}` is generic. Anyways I wish OP good luck trying to find a solution which doesn't cause more problems at some point or the other due to trying to unnecessarily shorten code.

Comment: @Harry I mean the same thing. I was just clarifying that what asker might want. I think he failed to ask the question in correct words.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660229/how-does-specificity-work-with-inherited-styles) I asked yesterday about how specificity works with inheritance.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: blue
}
```

The paragraph will be blue because:

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles

---

So if you want to set the color of a link via `body`, the only way that would work is if you knew that there weren't any selectors that directly target `a` tags. Because if something directly targeted the `a` tag, it would override your `body` style.